# How to fix issue with WebStorm HTML Live Edit opening when I press the "1" key?

Tags: javascript, html, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Currently in WebStorm 2019.2.3, when I am editing an HTML file and try to hit the <kbd>1</kbd> number key, WebStorm opens up Chrome and tries to display the HTML. This is very annoying, as it is preventing me from typing "1" anywhere, for example in H1 tags or font sizes.

I tried searching through the keymaps under preferences/settings and could not find this keybinding anywhere. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Select one of the bundled keymaps -- does it work any better?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find a mapped shortcut in the WebStorm Settings.

1. Go to the: WebStorm -> Preferences -> Keymap.
2. There is a search icon near with the input
3. Click it and type "1" in the input -> It will show you items that were mapped to this key.

[image]

Another option -  you can Reset the keymap to default.
[image]